# Resize elements and split layout at runtime

Tags: c#, wpf, split, resize

I have a simple problem in WPF/C#. 
I want to drag and drop some images into a layout and adjust their sizes according to the number of images (it can be more than 2!).

[image: What I want]

I have no problem with the Drag&Drop system. My problem is about the resizing elements/splitting the layout. I tried several things such as using `ItemsControl` with a `WrapPanel` but it is not working. I just see the image 1 in full size.

- How to do what I want ?
- Is the `ItemsControl` with a `WrapPanel` a good way ?
- How can I make that the WrapPanel will resize my images automatically ?

Here my XAML

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="list" AllowDrop="True" 
    Drop="list_Drop" Background="Transparent" Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" BorderBrush="{x:Null}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapPanel ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</ItemsControl>
```

And here my code-behind

```
private void list_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    Thumbnail thumbnail = sender as Thumbnail;
    Image addedImg = new Image();
    addedImg.Source = (BitmapImage)e.Data.GetData(typeof(BitmapImage));
    list.Items.Add(addedImg);
    this.UpdateLayout();
}
```

Thank you !

Comment: Can I see your `XAML`?

Comment: Yes of course! I will edit my question :)

Comment: Thank you MUG4N. I think pictures are always better than words :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ItemsControl with the ItemsPanel set to UniformGrid.

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ImagesList}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <UniformGrid/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</ItemsControl>
```